# Is there a better way of finding summary statistics in Python?

Tags: dataframe, statistics, dataset, data-science, python-3.7

The following is my code for finding the 5 point summary statistics. I keep getting this error:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not str

It seems like the way i'm using the describe function that i created is wrong.

```
from statistics import stdev,median,mean

def describe(key):
    a=[]
    for i in scripts:
        a.append(i[key])
    a=scripts[key]
    total = sum(script[key] for script in scripts)
    avg = total/len(a)
    avg=mean(a)
    s = stdev(a)
    q25 = min(a)+(max(a)-min(a))*25
    med = min(a)+(max(a)-min(a))*50
    med=median(a)
    q75 = min(a)+(max(a)-min(a))*75
    return (total, avg, s, q25, med, q75)`enter code here`
summary = [('items', describe('items')),
           ('quantity', describe('quantity')),
           ('nic', describe('nic')),
           ('act_cost', describe('act_cost'))]
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ba78d5218ead> in <module>()
----> 1 summary = [('items', describe('items')),
      2            ('quantity', describe('quantity')),
      3            ('nic', describe('nic')),
      4            ('act_cost', describe('act_cost'))]

<ipython-input-1-bcf37f98eb7d> in describe(key)
      4     for i in scripts:
      5         a.append(i[key])
----> 6     a=scripts[key]
      7     total = sum(script[key] for script in scripts)
      8     avg = total/len(a)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand your problem, since we don't know how `scripts` looks like. It is a global variable which is not defined in your script. The error states that `scripts` is of type `list`, but it looks like you assume it is a `dataframe` in your code. So please check the type of `scripts`.

Also, did you know that there is an easy way to calculate a Five-number summary with `numpy` like this:

```
import numpy as np
minimum, q25, med, q75, maximum = np.percentile(a, [0, 25, 50, 75, 100], interpolation='midpoint')
```

For description, see:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you are accessing list of dictionaries.
Directly accessing with its key value is not yielding the result here.

So you must do,
getValues = lambda key,inputData: [subVal[key] for subVal in inputData if key in subVal]

in this case,
getValues('key', scripts) will give the corresponding list, then its easy to compute the statistics of that list.